# My Laravel Web app on Virtual Host says curl is not enabled and .env file permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, webserver, laravel-8

I am hosting my Laravel web app using virtaul host on nginx ubuntu server. All configuration is ok and web app is running on subdomain but when when app start and it need to be configured it says curl is not enabled and .env file permission is denied. Please see image
[image]

Laravel destination folder is /var/www/mysite.
I am a beginner and following documentation and tutorial videos. I don;t know much about nginx,ubuntu and permissions. Please can someone guide me how can i enable permission and enable curl?

Comment: connect to your server, install curl `sudo apt-get install php7-curl`, change permissions `chmod 777 /var/www/mysite/.env`, `chmod 777 /var/www/mysite/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

Comment: thanks. permissions are ok now but curl is installed and my web app is still showing it with red flag

Comment: so check php.ini to enable `extention=php_curl` and check permission of all folder on your app to be 741, except bootstrap and storage and public (755). then restart your services.